# Update material, then change object's position. How to fix it?

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, augmented-reality, arkit

I am changing the SCNNode material. Then auto updating the object position and vibrat. How to fix the position? And click  button to How to remove all node in ARSCNView. I have attached update material code.

```
func updateMaterial() {

    sceneView.scene.rootNode.enumerateChildNodes { (node, stop) in
        let nod_name = node.name

        if nod_name != nil {
            if nod_name! == "triangle" {
                let material = SCNMaterial()
                let diffuseUrl = URL(string: "https://poly9.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/Arappfinish/Hexagon/Diffuse.jpg")
                let dimageData:NSData = NSData(contentsOf: diffuseUrl!)!
                 material.diffuse.contents = UIImage.sd_image(with: dimageData as Data)
                 material.isDoubleSided = true
                 material.diffuse.contentsTransform = SCNMatrix4MakeScale(8, -8, 8)
                 material.diffuse.wrapS = .repeat
                 material.diffuse.wrapT = .repeat
                 node.geometry!.materials = [material]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What happen if you comment this line `material.diffuse.contentsTransform = SCNMatrix4MakeScale(8, -8, 8)` and provide static image rather than downloading from URL